# How to recover a notebook emptied after kernel crash?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

While working in an ipython notebook, eventually I had to Ctrl+C as the kernel seemed to be halted.

The console gave me a message like:

```
[NotebookApp] Kernel  shutdown: 5faa86bf-........f6 
[NotebookApp] Kernel  shutdown: 71........22 
[NotebookApp] ....
```

(I had three notebooks running)

But something went wrong and my notebook file.ipynb is empty (actually only the one I was actively using).

Is there a way to recover that file before it was deleted? Some place where automatically-saved o manually-saved versions are stored?

(Running python 2.7 (Anaconda) in Windows 7)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can check in `.ipynb_checkpoints/` in the folder where your notebook was for recent enough version of IPython.

Comment: Don't forget to version control you data and to regularly commit ! :-)

Comment: I do, but the last commit had been 5 hours before :-)

Comment: Where on my computer might I find the `.ipynb_checkpoints/`. I just deleted some important cells. @Matt

Comment: In the same folder as the notebook you were working on. if workign on /foo/bar/qux.ipynb the save are on /foo/bar/.ipynb_checkpoints/qux-checkpoint.ipynb. You can also go to "file">"revert to checkpoint". Good time to also put your notebook on git or alike.

Comment: @Matt thanks, this was a life saver. I had actually committed, but the issue was that I reverted to a previous commit (hard reset), and by mistake overwrote my notebook. Using the checkpoints helped a lot

Answer (score 50):

If none of the above helped, I found a workaround to recover most of the changes I did since the last checkout - by simply calling this command in your notebook:

```
%history -g
```

If you want your IPython history in a plain-text file, you can export it yourself.

You can also do it for a specific filename:

```
%history -g -f filename
```

What does -g do? – Without -g it exports the history for the current session. 
With -g it exports history for all sessions.

Comment: this is a life saver answer!

Comment: This should have been marked as the right answer. Thanks.

Comment: `-f filename` will save the restored data (all previously run cells) to a new file, named `filename`. Note that this is a json file and not a jupyter notebook.

Comment: Gonna name my first child after you, Serendipity

Comment: You saved my day!

Comment: To recover specific cell from a specific session, use: `%history -n ~2/7-10 -f filename`. This recovers lines 7 to 10 from 2 sessions before the current and saves them in a file called "filename". Reference: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a great writeup about different recovery options from "Jupyter Disasters" at [1].

I want to quote one technique from there, namely opening `$HOME/.ipython/profile_default/history.sqlite` in the sqlite tool of your choice (e.g. sqlitebrowser) and digging around in there. This can be an option if there is no usable checkpoint file (as discussed in other answers).

[1] https://medium.com/flatiron-engineering/recovering-from-a-jupyter-disaster-27401677aeeb