# How to recover deleted Jupyter notebook cell?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I use Jupyter notebook. I accidentally deleted a cell, and I can't go step back.

How can I recover the notebook cell?

Answer (score 257, accepted):

If you go to "Edit", there's an option for "Undo Delete Cells".

**In MacOS**

If you are familiar with shortcuts, you can do <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd>  + <kbd>p</kbd> and then type in `undo` to recover as well. No need to moving your mouse around.

**In Windows**

First, switch to command mode by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then you can press <kbd>Z</kbd> to recover the deleted cells. (*Thanks to @nik7 who proposed this answer*)

Comment: This was removed in Jupyter Lab, see my answer to know how to do the same in Jupyter lab.

Comment: in jupyter lab it is "undo cell operation". this works to recover deleted cells **phew...!

Answer (score 127):

First, switch to command mode by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>, then you can press <kbd>Z</kbd> to recover the deleted cells. It works even in Jupyter Lab which doesn't have "Undo Delete Cells" option under "Edit" tab.

Comment: Works in VSCode too!

Answer (score 53):

If the notebook kernel is still running and you executed the cell, you can find the content of all cells, including the deleted ones in `_ih`. For example, the last five cells:

```
_ih[-5:]
```

Comment: In the sad case of closing the kernel, I've found out that simply opening an ipython console and scrolling back in history using the up arrow, shows the executed deleted cell. That's the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: A workaround to recover changes: export your IPython history in a plain-text file by calling "%history -g" 


You can also do it for a specific filename:

%history -g -f filename 
What does -g do? – Without -g it exports the history for the current session. With -g it exports history for all sessions.

Comment: OMG. %history saved my life...thank you very much :)

Comment: you absolute hero.

Answer (score 40):

If you need to **undo something deleted inside a cell**, press:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>

If you need to **recover an entire deleted cell** hit:
 <kbd>ESC</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>.
Especially this second tip might be useful if you delete a lot of cells by mistake.

Answer (score 10):

if you've already restarted your kernel then `%history` or `_ih[:n]` would be empty. You can hope for a recent checkpoint to revert to. You can do this with File > Revert to Checkpoint.

If you want to be sure what's in the checkpoint before you revert - in your working directory (the one your notebook lives in) you'll have a hidden folder that stores your checkpoints. `cd .ipynb_checkpoints` will get you there. You can look inside the file and see if your lost code is there.

This has just saved me. Found this in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356086/how-to-recover-a-notebook-emptied-after-kernel-crash/20357855)

Answer (score 4):

First, do "ESC" hot key, then you can press Z to recover the deleted cells.

Jupyter Lab work well.