# CountVectorizer tokenizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I have a dataframe with sentences which I used countvectorizer on with a pre-defined vocabulary.
For some of the vocabulary words, the return is 0 even though the sentences include the words in the dictionary.
the list of words that for some reason do not work are:

```
* 1 time
* 1 report
* 7 increase
* not a good fit
* not a great fit
* c level
* not a need
```

the CountVectorizer is defined as follows:

```
CountVectorizer(vocabulary=cols,ngram_range=(1,5))
```

where cols is the dictionary

I'm pretty sure this has to do with the tokenizer definitions but not sure how to change it to what I need
any help would be appreciated
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the solution on another post.
As expected, the default tokenization in CountVectorizer removes all special characters, punctuation and **single characters** which was my problem.
All I needed to do is change to token pattern as follows:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=cols,ngram_range=(1,5),token_pattern = r"(?u)\b\w+\b")
```

You can see the full explanation here:
[full explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48814309/how-to-recover-deleted-jupyter-notebook-cell)